# Using resx-string from pcl in axml?

Tags: c#, android, localization, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have the resx-files for localization in a portable-class-library in a class MyAppResources. So in code I can get localized strings just with:

```
 View.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCacheClear).Text = MyAppResources.TextClearCache;
```

But is there also a way to set this string already in the axml?

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnCacheClear"
     android:text= ??   />
```

Thx, Tom

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine the cleanest way would be to define a custom attribute that would read from your PCL resources via a `ResourceManager` .

I am working with MvvmCross, and got it working with a custom language binding parser:

```
public class CustomLanguageBindingParser : MvxBindingParser , IMvxLanguageBindingParser
{
    protected override MvxSerializableBindingDescription ParseBindingDescription()
    {
        this.SkipWhitespace();

        string resourceName = (string)this.ReadValue();

        // Pass the resource name in as the parameter on the StringResourceConverter.
        return new MvxSerializableBindingDescription
        {
            Converter = "StringResource",
            ConverterParameter = resourceName,
            Path = null,
            Mode = MvxBindingMode.OneTime
        };
    }

    public string DefaultConverterName { get; set; }

    public string DefaultTextSourceName { get; set; }
}
```

And a converter:

```
public class StringResourceConverter : IMvxValueConverter
{
    private static ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager(typeof(AppResources));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Ignore value. We are using parameter only.
        return manager.GetString((string)parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Register your parser in your MvxAndroidSetup class:

```
    protected override void InitializeIoC()
    {
        base.InitializeIoC();

        Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxLanguageBindingParser, CustomLanguageBindingParser>();
    }
```

In your .axml, define a namespace `xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

And invoke the resource. For example on a TextView: `local:MvxLang="Text MyResourceKey"`

This hooks into the MvvmCross binding system. The first part "Text" determines the target property, while the second part is parsed as a resource key. The language binding parser translates this into a binding with your custom converter and the key as the converter parameter. The converter does the string lookup based on the converter parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Using the string/any resources from RESX file in **Android Designer** is not supported, setting them from code is only possible way at the moment.

Comment: I found out that its working in Designer just with android:text="@string/TextClearCache". The string is taken from the PCL and is even changing properly according to the language in Designer. But it doesn't compile: Error  "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/TextClearCache')